# Docker Build command failing on windows 10 .Docker version used is 19.03.5

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

[image]When running docker build command it returns an error message as shown in the screen shot .

Ppath of the docker file:

```
C:\Users\****\dockerfiles
```

DockerFile.txt

```
# Base Alpine Linux based image with OpenJDK JRE only
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
# copy application WAR (with libraries inside)
COPY target/spring-boot-*.war /app.war
# specify default command
CMD ["/usr/bin/java", "-jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=test","/app.war"]
```

Comment: Usually commands like `docker build` produce textual error messages, not images.  Can you replace the image with the actual text of the error message?  You shouldn't usually paste screen shots of terminal windows or IDEs into SO questions.

Answer (score 0):

Create a directory called 'dockerfiles' under `C:\Users\username`
Keep the {`dockerfile without any extension`} under the newly created directory.
run the command `{from C:\Users\username directory}: docker build -t ./dockerfiles`